# Looking for a parsing program for files in a folder

Tags: parsing

I am looking for a software solution that will search for a specific string in a file name. ex: Search for: "1234" || Files Found: "A_1234" "B_1234"

When the program finds that file with the matching string, it will then open it and search for another string. ex: Search for: "foo" ||Files that are "1234" that contain "foo": "A_1234"

I can write my own code for it, I have a good idea on how to do it. Just looking for an existing solution so I do not have to make my own custom application.

Thanks!

Comment: as a beginner could you please try to specify programming language? it will be helpful for both of us

Comment: I am just looking for a software solution on Github or somewhere online. I posted this question to avoid making my own solution if something like this already exists.

Comment: You working windows or linux?

Comment: [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net)